# How to add numbers to the axes of a graph?

Tags: visualization, graphs, matplotlib

I am trying to make a graph of k (as in k-means) vs error, and I can't get it to show the actual number of k on the x-axis (1-15, not just the even numbers), nor any any numbers at all if I add a title to X.

I have looked at the data frame documentation and the matplotlib axes documentation, and I couldn't find anything telling me how to get it to show the numbers? Even if I have to manually specify them?

Please see images below:

```
rdf.plot.line(title='Number of clusters Vs mean accuracy')
```

[image: graph with bad xaxis numbers]

```
rdf.plot.line(title='Number of clusters Vs mean accuracy',
                x='parameters',
                y='mean_validation_score')
```

[image]

I don't understand how to get the x axis to show all 15 numbers (1-15).

Comment: Are the values of $k$ in your DataFrame?

Comment: They are, in the form of a column of dicts: `0      {'n_clusters': 1}
1      {'n_clusters': 2}
2      {'n_clusters': 3}` etc.

Comment: I would collapse that column into a purely numeric column, so that you can set it as the `x=` part of your plot command.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKeister , turns out that was (most of) the answer I used in the end. I extracted a list of the numbers and added them as the xtick parameter.

Comment: You're quite welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xticks`. e.g.

```
x=np.arange(1,16)
y = -60000*(3+np.log(1/x))
plt.plot(x,y,'b')
plt.xticks(x)
plt.show()
```

[image: example of xticks]

Comment: Thanks, I would upvote it but I don't have enough popularity points.

Comment: @ChorHataraHud'uKeturi No worries. Glad it helps.